# Unable to do cURL call from PHP terminal

Tags: php, curl, terminal, libcurl

Alright so I have cURL installed correctly, and am now trying to do a simple call to an URL, for some reason I'm not seeing anything happening in my database (The URL being called should make changes to my database, this is tested by calling the URL directly in my browser)

This is my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.website.com/receive/001/ALKDLDKGJLKSD/ASIODULKJASFL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In my terminal I am getting the following response:

```
´╗┐
```

Am I just misunderstanding how cURL should be used for a simple web request?

Comment: What happens if you replace the URL with some that actually produces any output (like a URL of this SO question)?

Comment: Do I understand right that your page does not produce any output?

Comment: Did you check web server log file, if it got the call?

Comment: Yes, the page is not producing any output, it's more of a cronjob, call a URL and the website will execute code without any return value

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. It retrieves the HTTP page (I've tested it on my terminal).

---

The three characters you are getting is probably a [UTF-8 byte order mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

```
0xEF,0xBB,0xBF
```

Either it is what the page returns. Or you have these at the beginning on your PHP script (some editors put these implicitly to the text files, the characters won't show in the editor itself).

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working, it looked like there was some security behind the URL I tried to access, silly me for not checking that correctly. Still many thanks for all the suggestions!